# Creating indirect thread barriers for field members?

Tags: multithreading, rust, parallel-processing

I am attempting to do the followwing let;s say you have a structure like this:

```rs
struct MyStruct
{
  data1 : Vec<usize>
}



   fn function(obj : &mut MyStruct, i: usize)
   {
       obj.data1[i] += obj.data1[(i - obj.data1[i]) % obj.data1.len()];
   }
```

You are not allowed to modify the structure, but the function can be modified. We will call the function once on all elements of `data1` and we will assume the struct is initialised appropriately. We don't care about the result.

We want to parallelize this operation, thus we want mutexes to prevent multiple threads from writing to the same memory location at once. Since we cannot add the mutexes to the struct directly, we can make something like this:

```rs
pub struct ThreadedDataLocks<'a, T>(Vec<Mutex<&'a mut T>>);

impl<'a, T> ThreadedDataLocks<'a, T>
{
    pub fn at(&mut self, i: usize) -> MutexGuard<'_, &'a mut T>
    {
        self.0[i].lock().unwrap()
    }
}
```

To try to create a set of indirect handles into the data with which to mutate it. The problem is that now for as long as that object exists, you cannot pass `MyStruct` anywhere, because the borrow checker marries your object instantiation to the indirect handles.

I am going insane trying to find a sane way to make this work.

Comment: Did you mean to call the field `data1`?

Comment: Are you aware that parallelism may change the result, because it will change the order at which elements are modified? And are you aware that using a mutex will likely defeat any speed gain from the parallelism?

Comment: Why do you need to move `MyStruct` while it is borrowed?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I am aware, it is fine, the actual result for this case doesn't matter.

Comment: @drewtato Yes sorry, that was a typo

Comment: @ChayimFriedman this is the smallest working example I could com up with. The reason is, I have a much more complex codebase where I am trying to achieve something similar.

Comment: But you can't move something while it is borrowed. This is a fact we cannot change. If you elaborate on your real use-case, maybe we will be able to help.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The real case is that I have a threadpool. And I have a fluid simulation whose  state is in a struct of arrays format. My goal is to  parallelize the logic of the fluid simulation without changing the definition of the sturcture. i.e. finding some way to access the struct fields through mutexes without adding or  removing fields to the struct.

Comment: But why do you need to move the borrowed struct?

Comment: When you create a set of mutexes to contain handles into the data to the struct, rust considers that equivalent to borrowing the struct itself.

Comment: Yes, sure, but why do you need to move the struct? You can just handle everything via the mutexes.

Comment: I cannot, because that struct lives in a different scope that still needs to access its data. in particular I need to be able to copy the data after it has been modified inside  the threads. But I can't do that under the current ownership model because it forces me to put the overal structure inside of a mutex, which then des not allow me to create the handle si need to the underlying data...

Comment: But if you need to copy only after the threads have finished their work, what's the problem? The value is no longer borrowed.